# Queryset - How find a word in foreign key in django?

Tags: django

How find a word in a foreign key?

There are classes:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    order =    models.ForeignKey('Order')

class Orders(models.Model):
    orderName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

There are these records in Customer and order tables:

Order:

```
+-----+------------------+
| id  | orderName        |
+-----+------------------+
| 1   | Apple juice      |
+-----+------------------+
| 2   | Apple pie        |
+-----+------------------+
| 3   | Banana juice     |
+-----+------------------+
| 4   | Banana pie       |
+-----+------------------+
| 5   | Apple ice cream |
+-----+------------------+
| ... | ...              |
+-----+------------------+
```

Customer:

```
+-----+----------+-------+
| id  | Customer | Order |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 1   | A        | 2     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 2   | B        | 3     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 3   | C        | 2     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 4   | G        | 1     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 5   | H        | 1     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| ... | ...      | ...   |
+-----+----------+-------+
```

I want to get all the records in the customer table that their orders consist of "Apple".
I wrote these codes:

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order='Apple')
```

I got an error message:

> Field expected a number but got 'Apple'.

How should change the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the `orderName` of the related `Orders` objects contains that name, for example with:

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order__orderName__icontains='Apple')
```

or for a case *sensitive* match:

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order__orderName__contains='Apple')
```

or you can make use of a regex with word boundaries:

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order__orderName__iregex=r'\bApple\b')
```

or if you want to only match orders that have `'Apple'`:

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order__orderName='Apple')
```

or for case insenstive matching:

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order__orderName__iexact='Apple')
```

Comment: Also if there may be a lot of other items and apple may be in the name like "Pineapple" then he should use iexact or exact

Answer (score 1):

Span your relationship lookup by using **`__`** (double underscore)

```
all_apple_orders = Customer.objects.filter(order__orderName__icontains='Apple')
```

Reference: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)